# Keras: linear model unstable results

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to apply linear model to MNIST dataset and it works, but it's 'unstable', i.e. each re-run of code can produce drastically different results in terms of accuracy. I understand that NN learn weights in 'stochastic' way and maybe solution converges to different local minima, but maybe there some way to make it more 'stable'?

Here is my model definition:

```
def get_model():
    w=28
    h=28
    input_shape = (w*h,)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='linear', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

    print(model.summary())

    return model
```

**Update:** seems adding regularization is valid answer to initial question of instability of solution in terms of accuracy.

```
def get_model():
    w=28
    h=28
    input_shape = (w*h,)
    model = Sequential()

    #v1 - Not valid, because applying softmax to one layer network is meaningless
    #model.add(Dense(n_classes, init='uniform', activation='linear',
    #   kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
    #   activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01),
    #   input_shape=input_shape))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    #model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    #v2
    model.add(Dense(n_classes, init='uniform', activation='softmax',
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01),
    input_shape=input_shape))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

    #print(model.summary())

    return model
```

Comment: Why is your activation linear?

Comment: there is no regularization in your model

Comment: @Coldspeed not sure if 'linear' can be replaced with 'Relu' before Softmax, anyway `model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', input_shape=input_shape))` performs similar.

Comment: @mrgloom Softmax should be considered for your output layer only. For your hidden layers, try either relu, tanh or sigmoid depending on your use case. Personally, tanh is a good option because it squashes your output leading to a smooth activation.

Comment: @Coldspeed but for example `model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))` here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py#L42 assumes that output of last layer is used as input to softmax without applying any activation?

Comment: @mrgloom I think you're misunderstanding! Each neural network has an input layer, one or more hidden layers, and an output layer (with softmax in your case). It seems you only have one output layer, and no hidden layers. The activation on its own does not constitute a layer.

Comment: @Coldspeed I'm trying to define linear model such as [n_samples,n_dim] *[n_dim,n_classes] = [n_samples,n_classes], so in my understanding this NN have 1 layer.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut seems you are right adding regularization is valid answer to initial question of instability of solution in terms of accuracy.

Comment: @Coldspeed he is building a linear model for multiclass classification, that's totally feasible.

Comment: @mrgloom glad it helped, I add this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L1/L2 regularization or dropout should help to stablize the learning here.

Comment: But dropout can be only applied to input image and can't be applied to output of single layer, I'm right?

Comment: @mrgloom dropout is just another "layer" that you can put between input and output.

Comment: I mean it's meaningless to zero portion of output before use as direct input to softmax.